# Getting Device ID is not unique

Tags: ios, swift

I really have problem with getting unique deviceID.
The code I am using now it this :

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
```

I need it to be unique because it will be used at every async call
Here is my state

1.Install app from Xcode (using that deviceID which is first time generated.)
2.Then I remove the app.
3.Then I install the app again from Xcode.
4.Device ID changed

So,how to make it unique to only one device = one id no matter where it install Xcode,TestFlight,AppStore.

Comment: As you've noticed, the vendor identifier is discarded when the application is removed.  Short of some form of remote authorization and storage, there's not much way to keep the identifier persistent around remove and reinstall.  That's really pretty much the whole point of removing access to the UDID and other persistent identifiers.

Comment: It might be possible to work around it using the Security storage options, but I'm thinking even those are erased with the application.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561938/is-there-a-persistent-replacement-for-udid

Comment: Here we go, looks like this question is pretty much identical to yours.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878560/how-to-preserve-identifierforvendor-in-ios-after-uninstalling-ios-app-on-device

Comment: @DavidBerry,can you help me out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520040/working-with-access-control-in-swift